# View all instances crossed a threshold on AWS CloudWatch in the past month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Looking to list all EC2 servers/instances which have crossed a certain threshold using AWS CloudWatch

I want to view all my ec2 instances or servers which have reached or crossed some threshold i.e triggered some alarm, in any time in the last one month. I have been looking for a solution for the past two days but to no avail. I would really appreciate any help regarding the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **alarm** in **CloudWatch** for an **EC2 metric** (e.g., CPUUtilization) **for all instances** by selecting a metric like this **EC2 -> Across All Instances -> CPUUtilization**. Then you can select a value for **Statistic (e.g., Maximum)** and a specify a **period** over which you need the alarm to check **for alert (e.g., 1 Minute)**. Under conditions, select **Threshold type (e.g., Static)**, chose the **condition operator (e.g., Greater > threshold)**, define the **threshold value (e.g., 75.0)**. Under Notification, select the value for **Whenever this alarm state is (e.g., in Alarm)** and Select an **SNS topic**. Finally, specify other values like name, description, etc and create the alarm.